# Renew \chapterheadstart for numbered chapters only (memoir)

Tags: memoir

I am redefining the chapter styles for my document - one of the tasks I want to achieve is to add an image in front of all *numbered* chapters. The question / problem I have is, how to target only the numbered chapters (or exclude ToC, bibliography, appendix A-[Z], etc.).

My current code - slightly simplified to include only a chapterheadstart command with an added vspace for 'numbered' chapters. Unfortunately this does not work and instead removes the 'vspace' from all of the chapters;

```
\makechapterstyle{styleName}{
\ifnum\value{secnumdepth}>-1 
  \if@mainmatter
    \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{
      \vspace*{5cm}
      \noindent
    }
  \fi
\fi
}
```

Thank you in advance! Definte beginner in LaTeX here.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why not define two chapter styles, and apply them as needed? All the numbered chapters would be contiguous, and you'd only need three `\chapterstyle` commands for the whole document (one for the front matter (unnumbered lists of things), one for the main matter (numbered chapters), and one for the bibliography and back matter).

Comment: @MikeRenfro Thank you for the suggestion! Does that mean adding '\chapterstyle{1}' at the beginning of my .tex document, and adding '\chapterstyle{2}' where my main document text starts? (And adding \chapterstyle{3} for the final chapters)

Comment: Yes. The truly picky among us could modify the `\mainmatter` or similar commands with `\addtodef` to automatically include the `\chapterstyle` commands. But that's only relevant if you're making a document class for others and want to minimize the amount of code they have to deal with.

Comment: @MikeRenfro The solution you proposed works for me! If you appreciate it, please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `\chapterstyle` commands to make transitions from one style to another. They will take effect from that point on in the document.

```
\documentclass[openany]{memoir} % openany to reduce blank pages
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\chapterstyle{bianchi} % for ToC and other lists

\tableofcontents

\chapterstyle{bringhurst} % for numbered chapters

\chapter{One}
From \cite{golub13}, \lipsum[1]

\chapterstyle{chappell} % for bibliography, appendices, etc. May be same as for ToC.
\bibintoc
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{golub13}
Gene~H. Golub and Charles~F. van Loan.
\newblock {\em Matrix Computations}.
\newblock JHU Press, 4th edition, 2013.

\end{thebibliography}

\appendix

\chapter{Appendix}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Early pages:

[image]

Numbered chapters:

[image]

Bibliography:

[image]

Appendices:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Memoir tests itself if it has to print a chapter number in `\@makechapterhead` with `\ifm@m@And`. This only works, though, if not the starred version of `\chapter` is used. Hence we also test if not a starred chapter is started with `\ifm@mpn@new@chap`.

```
\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{styleName}{
    \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{
        \ifm@m@And % If there is no number to print
            \ifm@mpn@new@chap % This is to catch the starred version
                \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}\\[5cm]
            \fi
        \fi
    }
}
\makeatother
```

And integrated into the MWE of Mike Renfro:

```
\documentclass[openany]{memoir} % openany to reduce blank pages
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{styleName}{
    \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{
        \ifm@m@And % If there is no number
            \ifm@mpn@new@chap % This is to catch the starred version
                \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}\\[5cm]
            \fi
        \fi
    }
}
\makeatother
\chapterstyle{styleName}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}
From \cite{golub13}, \lipsum[1]

\chapter*{Two}

\bibintoc
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{golub13}
Gene~H. Golub and Charles~F. van Loan.
\newblock {\em Matrix Computations}.
\newblock JHU Press, 4th edition, 2013.

\end{thebibliography}

\appendix

\chapter{Appendix}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```